# rails 3.1: Is it ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In rails 3.1, I implement as:
1. Define test action in post controller:

```
def test
    @p = Post.first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

2. Define in routes.rb:

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    get 'test'
  end
end
```

3. In index.html.erb of post folder, I add link:

```
<%= link_to "test", test_post_path, :remote => true %>
```

4. Create test.js.erb file in post folder:

```
code jQuery
```

My question is: "Is my implement Ajax in rails 3.1?" I don't really understand about ajax in rails.
If no, can you give me a link about ajax in rails 3.1 and the technique I set up, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is ajax. When you add `:remote => true` to links and forms in rails, it automatically sends data to the server without refreshing your page on the browser. That's how ajax works in every language/script.

In your case, you can put js code in your test.js.erb file to update/interact the page (with jQuery). You might want to update some html div elements with the attributes of instance variable you set up `@p` .

Eg. in your test.js.erb

```
$("#some_div").html("<%= @p.title%>");
```

Then you have essentially made an ajax request to the server and update the client browser page with the server data without refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You request is do by Ajax from your link. But the return of your action can be not usefull to you.

You need add in your `app/view/posts` directory a test.js.erb file and fill it with Javascript behaviour you want.